# $lookup with condition in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 schemas, this is parent collection schema:

```
  const TimesheetSchema = Schema({
    managersComment: {
        type: String,
    },
    weekNum: {
        type: Number,
    },
    year: {
        type: Number,
    },
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: userModel },
    status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Saved", "Submitted", "Approved", "Rejected"],
    },
    data: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: TimesheetIndividualData }]
});
```

This is child collection schema

```
  const TimesheetDataSchema = new Schema(
    {
        workingDate: {
            type: Date,
        },
        dayVal: {
            type: Number,
        },
        user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: userModel },
        parentId: { type: String }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

In `TimesheetDataSchema` parentId is basically the _id from `TimesheetSchema`.

Now i need to run a query which return docs from TimesheetDataSchema, but only the docs in which parentId(ObjectId) of `TimesheetSchema`  has status `Approved`.

I am trying to do $lookup, but currently no success. Please help.

EDIT: Based upon @ashh suggestion tried this: but getting empty array.

```
const result = await TimesheetIndividualData.aggregate([
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "timesheetModel",
                "let": { "parentId": "$parentId" },
                "pipeline": [
                    { "$match": { "status": "Approved", "$expr": { "$eq": ["$weekNum", "$parentId"] } } },
                ],
                "as": "timesheet"
            }
        },
        { "$match": { "timesheet": { "$ne": [] } } }
    ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
const result = await db.TimesheetDataSchema.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "TimesheetSchema",
    "let": { "parentId": "$parentId" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "status": "approved", "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$parentId"] }}},
    ],
    "as": "timesheet"
  }},
  { "$match": { "timesheet": { "$ne": [] }} }
])
```

But I would prefer two queries for better performance here

```
const timesheets = (await db.TimesheetSchema.find({ status: "approved" }, { _id: 1 })).map(({ _id }) => _id)
const result = await db.TimesheetDataSchema.find({ parentId: { $in: timesheets } })
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion, but getting empty array, please see edit, not sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: @raju check the `"from": "TimesheetSchema"` part in the first query. It should also work